# Gitbook editor online plugin

Tags: document, gitbook

I've installed `gitbook` on my local machine. However, I didn't see the online editor with it. I search the editor plugin for it, but I only find these two, [edit-link](https://plugins.gitbook.com/plugin/edit-link) and [github-edit](https://plugins.gitbook.com/plugin/github-edit).

But they both need to edit the file on `github` or `gitlab`. Is there any plugin I can edit on my local `gitbook` without them? Like gitbook itself.

[image]